# Migrate TSLint to ESLint in Angular with multiple projects, ng lint command hangs

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint

I have successfully migrated another Angular 10 app with a single project from TSLint to ESLint, following the instructions of [Angular ESLint](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-from-codelyzer-and-tslint). When I try to migrate an Angular 10 app with multiple projects under the projects/ folder (i.e. 'app' and 'myLib') and try to run 'ng lint' or 'npx ng lint app', then I only see 'Linting "app"...' and the command seems to hang. All required packages have been installed and the migration phase was errorless. Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm facing the exact same issue

Comment: some very interesting info on this topic here : https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#notes-on-performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual problem was that linter was executed very very slowly (so slow that seemed to hang, unless you use debug), so in order for the issue to be fixed, in the inner `.eslintrc.json` of each project, under `parserOptions`, in the `project` array, I added `tsconfig.json`

```
"parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "projects/app/tsconfig.app.json",
          "projects/app/tsconfig.spec.json",
          "projects/app/e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ]
}
```

Comment: @Drenai I'm assuming it clears up the config and sets the baseurls. It is an assumption though. It really does work though, well done. Koninos.